# Blurry library doesn't blur buttons

Tags: android, blur, graphic, blurry

I am blurring constraint layout with Blurry Library and only buttons doesn't blur. Any solutions?

[image]

```
@BindView(R.id.constraintLayout) ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
@BindView(R.id.return_button) ImageButton returnButton;
@BindView(R.id.email) EditText email;
@BindView(R.id.password) EditText password;
@BindView(R.id.button_login) AppCompatButton buttonLogin;
@BindView(R.id.forgot_password_button) AppCompatButton forgotPasswordButton;


 Blurry.with(getApplicationContext())
            .radius(25)
            .async()
            .animate(500)
            .sampling(8)
            .onto(constraintLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i made it working. I just move buttons to FrameLayout